# httpd.conf in mountain lion

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion, httpd.conf

I am using Mountain Lion, and I put website under
`/Users/myname/Sites`.
After checking the the apache folder, I found two `httpd.conf`, one of them is:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and another is:

```
/private/etc/apache2/users/myname.conf
```

What's the relationship between these two?
If I wanna add some rewrite directives, can I just put them into `myname.conf`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The httpd.conf in `/private/etc/apache2/` is the global config for the apache server. The config file in `/private/etc/apache2/users/` is related to the user directory. The way Apache is configured on OSX loads a user directory, accessed through `/~myname`.